# Why is UIWindow's bounds always in portrait regardless of the app's supported interface orientation?

Tags: ios, orientation, ios8

Why is UIWindow's bounds always in portrait regardless of the app's supported interface orientation? Has this changed in iOS 8.

Comment: Try it. What do you get?

Comment: I got what I asked but I am not sure if I cover all scenarios and why UIWindow behaves this way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that under iOS 8, an app started up in landscape will indicate the `UIWindow` bounds with its landscape size.

Comment: @rmaddy In view debugging, it's showing UIWindow as portrait.  App deployment target is 7.1.

Answer (score 3):

The window coordinate system for iOS8 SDK-compiled apps has changed. Getting the bounds will now return the bounds of the window in view coordinates rather than screen coordinates. Thus, you should not perform any correction based on the current orientation. This is likewise implemented for keyboard frame retrieved in notifications.

So a landscape window will now appear as {0, 0, 480, 320}, rather than {0, 0, 320, 480}.

To support both iOS7 and iOS8, keep your logic for determining the width and height according to orientation, and just fake the orientation of the window as portrait if on iOS8.

---

Internally what happens, when a window has a root view controller, the system resizes the window according to the root view controller's view's transform. If there is no root view controller, the coordinate system remains as before.